# Ошибка com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.example.mychat.AwesomeMessage

Tags: java, android, xml

Пишу пробное приложение чат, ни как не могу решить данную ошибку:

> (com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.example.mychat.AwesomeMessage)

Bесь интернет облазил, все руководства прочитал, помогите пожалуйста.

MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView messageListView;
    private AwesomeMessageAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageButton sendImageButton;
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private EditText messageEditText;

    private String userName;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference messagesDatabaseReference;
    ChildEventListener messagesChildEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://chat-41f73-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
        messagesDatabaseReference = database.getReference().child("messages");

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        sendImageButton = findViewById(R.id.sendPhotoButton);
        sendMessageButton = findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);

        userName = "Default User";

        messageListView = findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        List<AwesomeMessage> awesomeMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AwesomeMessageAdapter(this, R.layout.message_item,
                awesomeMessages);
        messageListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        messageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    sendMessageButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    sendMessageButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        messageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]
                {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(500)});

        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AwesomeMessage message = new AwesomeMessage();
                message.setText(messageEditText.getText().toString());
                message.setName(userName);
                message.setImageUrl(null);

                messagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);

                messageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        sendImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        messagesChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                //////////////////////////////////
                // !!! ошибка на данной строке !!!
                AwesomeMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(AwesomeMessage.class);
                adapter.add(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        messagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(messagesChildEventListener);
    }
}
```

myAdapter:

```
public class AwesomeMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AwesomeMessage> {
    public AwesomeMessageAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                                 List<AwesomeMessage> messages) {
        super(context, resource, messages);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.message_item, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView photoImageView = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        TextView textTextView = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textTextView);
        TextView nameTextView = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        AwesomeMessage message = getItem(position);

        boolean isText = message.getImageUrl() == null;

        if (isText) {
            textTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textTextView.setText(message.getText());
        } else {
            textTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getImageUrl())
                    .into(photoImageView);
        }

        nameTextView.setText(message.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Class:

```java
public class AwesomeMessage {

    String text;
    String name;
    String imageUrl;

    public AwesomeMessage() {
    }

    public AwesomeMessage(String text, String name, String imageUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Ошибка в `MainActivity :: ChildEventListener :: onChildAdded` на строке `dataSnapshot.getValue(AwesomeMessage.class);`

(на всякий случай мой message_item.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
Process: android.example.mychat, PID: 5375
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.example.mychat.AwesomeMessage
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:423)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
        at android.example.mychat.MainActivity$4.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Замените `setValue(Object value)` на `setValue(Object value,DatabaseReference.CompletionListener listener)`. Может ошибка в колбэке вернется. Далее смотрите что в базе, в консоли. Смотрите что возвращает dataSnapshot.getValue(). Выглядит как не сложный дебаг...

Answer (score 0):

В узел "messages" предварительно были добавлены String с данными, а ты пытаешься получить Object (в твоём случае AwesomeMessage).Зайди в консоль Firebase и проверь чтобы все данные в узле были в виде объектов сохранены...если нет по удаляй лишнее.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/717046)